# Module can not be imported

Tags: python

as illustrated in the below posted code, as referring to the paths mentioned in the screen shot attached, i am trying to import the class `ProofOfConcept_1`
but at run time i receive the following error;

```
PS M:\projects\python\flask apps\openRoutService\apps\app5\app5-test> & C:/Python310/python.exe "m:/projects/python/flask apps/openRoutService/apps/app5/app5-test/multiprocessingTests/PoolExexOnPoolExecConcept/start.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m:\projects\python\flask apps\openRoutService\apps\app5\app5-test\multiprocessingTests\PoolExexOnPoolExecConcept\start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from multiprocessingTests.PoolExexOnPoolExecConcept.ProofOfConcept_1 import ProofOfConcept_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocessingTests'
```

please let me know how should i correctly import the class `ProofOfConcept_1`

**start.py**

```
from multiprocessingTests.PoolExexOnPoolExecConcept.ProofOfConcept_1 import ProofOfConcept_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ProofOfConcept_1.parallel()
```

**ProofOfConcept_1.py**:

```
import time
import logging
import logging.config
import configparser
from multiprocessingTests.PoolExexOnPoolExecConcept.TreatmentPoolExec import TreatmentPoolExec
from multiprocessingTests.PoolExexOnPoolExecConcept.BufferPoolExec import BufferPoolExec
from utils.PoolUtils import PoolUtils
from Multiprocessing.KeyAndNoneKeyGridCells.pool.GridCellsProfiles.VarTasksDispatcher import VarTasksDispatcher
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
})
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('configs.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class ProofOfConcept_1(object):
    
    @staticmethod
    def parallel():        
        strtTime = time.time()
        
        processesCount, procsRem = PoolUtils.getProcessesCountPerPool(numOfPools=2,processesCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['processes_count']))
        cpuCount, cpuRem = PoolUtils.getCpuCountPerPool(numOfPools=2,cpuCount=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['cpu_count']))
        calcETRRiskInTreatmentForResourcesPoolExec = TreatmentPoolExec(processCount=processesCount+procsRem,cpuCount=cpuCount+cpuRem)
        calcETRRiskInTreatmentForResourcesPoolExec.setIterables([0])
        calcETRRiskInBufferForResourcesPoolExec = BufferPoolExec(processCount=processesCount,cpuCount=cpuCount)
        calcETRRiskInBufferForResourcesPoolExec.setIterables([0])
        calcETRRiskPoolExecList = []
        calcETRRiskPoolExecList.append(calcETRRiskInTreatmentForResourcesPoolExec)
        calcETRRiskPoolExecList.append(calcETRRiskInBufferForResourcesPoolExec)
        varTasksDispatcher = VarTasksDispatcher()
        '''no results to be sent back'''
        res = varTasksDispatcher.dispatch(calcETRRiskPoolExecList)
```

**path**:

[image]

Comment: @SinaMobasheri the loc of start.py, is as shown in the screen shot, it is inside the folder PoolExecOnPoolExecConcept

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you pass a Python source file directly to the interpreter, the interpreter is not aware of what package Python files are part of, if you want to run a Python file inside the package you must use `-m` flag and pass the dot-separated path of python file (module) to it. 
Second, a directory containing Python files is a package and behaves correctly when it contains `__init__.py`. If it does not contain one, it's a namespace and behaves differently compared to a package.

With these two fixes, you should be able to go to `m:\projects\python\flask apps\openRoutService\apps\app5\app5-test` and run `python -m multiprocessingTests.PoolExexOnPoolExecConcept.start`.

If you are planning to be a Python developer please watch [this amazing talk about how python import system works by *David Beazley*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0), it will clear up a lot of things for you.